# How do I display hidden image when i click list on html using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

for example, all images are hidden and when I click list, it should pop up. if I click "Hello1" text then image1 should popup

```
<li class nav-1><a href="#">Hello1</a></li>
<li class nav-1><a href="#">Hello2</a></li>
<li class nav-1><a href="#">Hello3</a></li>

<img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Comment: you can do it through java script but you have to consider giving ID for each element so you can select element by id and change the display to none to hide it or show it as block .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add id's to your images and put in a basic hide/unhide script:

```html
<script>
function toggleHide(elementid){
a=document.getElementById(elementid).style.visibility;
if (a=="hidden"){
document.getElementById(elementid).style.visibility="visible";
}else{
document.getElementById(elementid).style.visibility="hidden";
}
}
</script>
<style>
/* hide all images */
#img1{
visibility:hidden;
}
#img2{
visibility:hidden;
}
#img3{
visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
<li class nav-1><a href="#" onclick="toggleHide('img1')">Hello1</a></li>
<li class nav-1><a href="#" onclick="toggleHide('img2')">Hello2</a></li>
<li class nav-1><a href="#" onclick="toggleHide('img3')">Hello3</a></li>

<img src="images/1.jpg" id="img1" alt=""/>
<img src="images/2.jpg" id="img2" alt=""/>
<img src="images/3.jpg" id="img3" alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, I used `div` instead of `img`, but the concept is the same...

Read the comments for more details please:

```js
// Get the buttons and the images
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');

// For each button:
buttons.forEach(btn => {
    // Onclick event:
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
        // Get all the images and remove the 'active' class
        images.forEach(image => { image.classList.remove('active'); });
     
        // Get the id of the clicked button (which is the data-image of the target image)
        let target = btn.getAttribute('id');
        
        // Add the class 'active' to the image
        document.querySelector(`[data-image="${target}"]`).classList.add('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    display: none;
}

.image.active {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="image1">Image 1</button>
<button class="btn" id="image2">Image 2</button>
<button class="btn" id="image3">Image 3</button>


<div class="image" data-image="image1">1</div>
<div class="image" data-image="image2">2</div>
<div class="image" data-image="image3">3</div>
```